# Hibernate : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I get this error : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

With this HQL :

```
select new map(r,count(pt)) from Role r
                    inner join r.portfolioTeams pt
                    inner join pt.teamStatusTransitions ptst
                    inner join ptst.teamStatus tst
                    where pt.id.bankId = :bankId 
                    and pt.id.networkDistributorId = :networkDistributorId 
                    and ptst.id.startDate  <= :startDate 
                    and (ptst.endDate is null or ptst.endDate > :endDate) 
                    and tst.id.teamStatusId in (:statusId) 
                    and (r.id.cpmRoleId in (:roles) OR r.id.cpmRoleId in (:roles1) )
```

I checked, there is no missing parenthesis, I'm pretty sure it comes from my count(pt).

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the generated SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers,

finally i resolve it with keywork "element" in my count and then with a group by

```
select new map(r as roleKey,count(elements(pt)) as nbTeamKey) from Role r
                inner join r.portfolioTeams pt
                inner join pt.teamStatusTransitions ptst
                inner join ptst.teamStatus tst
                where pt.id.bankId = :bankId 
                and pt.id.networkDistributorId = :networkDistributorId 
                and ptst.id.startDate  <= :startDate 
                and (ptst.endDate is null or ptst.endDate > :endDate) 
                and tst.id.teamStatusId in (:statusId) group by r
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not all your variables (:bankId, :networkDistributorId, :startDate, :endDate, :statusId, :roles, :roles1) are bound when executing the query?

Answer (score -1):

What do you see when turning show_sql=true for hibernate config? Have you tried running the generated script directly on the database with replacing binding parameters?

Sometime, database like ORACLE will give you missing right parenthesis error if you have not properly used quotes (for example, you should be using '' instead of ' in some cases), resulting into syntax error.